# How to Restore From Generate Scripts

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, backup

I have created a back up for a SQL Server database using the "Generate scripts" options and I am including the data.

I have created the scripts separately so I have one file for each object.

How do I know which order to run the scripts in?

Comment: The quick answer is that you don't. One way to get out that pit is to disable constraints before executing your scripts (in whatever order) and re-enable them at the end. Provided you know what you are doing.

Comment: If you have access to the old database you can create an <database>.bak file or copy the <database>.mdf, <database>.ldf file

Answer (score 0):

1. Drop Constraints
2. Create Objects
3. Insert Data
4. Recreate Constraints

Now you need to figure out which scripts do what and order them accordingly. I suggest you run them using a quick tool (coded in any language of your choice, c#, batch file, even SQL) reading the order in which they are to be executed from a table. In this way , even if it fails you can rearrange easily. How many scripts are we looking at btw? if it's greater than 50 , better to have a  systematic and planned approach.

If possible, best to take a new full backup and restore (without involving any scripts of course).